# C++: Inheriting functions that return base class pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class `Base` and a class that inherits it called `Derived`. Class `Base` has a virtual function `returnPtrToSelf()` that returns a pointer to itself. `Derived` has its original member function `derivedFunc()` which `Base` has not.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual Base* returnPtrToSelf() {
        return this;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void derivedFunc() {
        std::cout << "i am derived" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.derivedFunc();                                   // works
    d.returnPtrToSelf()->derivedFunc();                // ERROR
    ((Derived*)d.returnPtrToSelf())->derivedFunc();    // works
}
```

The error will not go away unless I implement `Derived`'s own `returnPtrToSelf()` that returns a `Derived*`.

I am making a lot of derived classes and think it is tedious to implement an original version of this function for each derived class. Is there a more convenient way of fixing that error other than this tedious way?

Comment: What about using a `static_cast<Derived*>(d.returnPtrToSelf())` instead? `Base` doesn't declare any function member `derivedFunc()`, thus you can't access it via a `Base*` pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is essentially what they did in the last line (except with a C-style cast)

Comment: If you are making lots of derived classes which have methods that are not in the base, and you want to call those methods, your code will be tedious no matter what. To avoid tedium, re-design the code.

Comment: Could CRTP help here? ...though, what's wrong with simply using the address-of operator?

Comment: @celticminstrel Yes, CRTP would be merely the static polymorphism solution of what I've been describing in my answer. The OP should refactor their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. If `derivedFunc` is really something that anything that inherits from `Base` should support, then that should be reflected in `Base`:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    void func() override { std::cout << "i am derived" << std::endl; }
};

Base* b = new Derived;
b->func();
```

If `derivedFunc` is *only* applicable to a `Derived`, then it wouldn't make any sense to be able to access it from `Base` anyway. What if `Base` were a `AnotherDerived` instead? In those cases where you really need to call `derivedFunc`, just have your functions take a `Derived*` (or `Derived&`) instead of a `Base*` (or `Base&`).

As a last resort, if there's really some case where you absolutely need to call `derivedFunc` on a `Derived` uniquely, then there's always:

```
void maybeCallDerivedFunc(Base* b) {
    if (auto d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b)) {
        d->derivedFunc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am making a lot of derived classes and think it is tedious to implement an original version of this function for each derived class. Is there a more convenient way of fixing that error other than this tedious way?"*

I'd say that's a classical case to use the [Template Method Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html):

```
 class Base {
 public:
     void func() {
         funcImpl();
     }
     virtual ~Base() {}
 protected:
     Base() {}
     virtual void funcImpl() = 0;
 };

 class DerivedA : public Base {
 public:
     DerivedA() {}
 protected:
     void funcImpl() {
         // DerivedA special implementation
     }
 };

 class DerivedB : public Base {
 public:
     DerivedB() {}
 protected:
     void funcImpl() {
          // DerivedB special implementation
     }
 };
```

Call in main would look like

```
int main() {
    DerivedA dA;
    DerivedB dB;
    dA.func();
    dB.func();
}
```

This is especially useful, if every class derived from `Base` should contribute some specialized piece for some more complex logic going on in `Base::func()`.

---

This could be achieved in a similar way using a templated base class (without need for the vtable overhead), and merely encapsulating the cast applied in your `main()` function:

```
 template<typename Derived>
 class Base {
 public:
     void func() {
         static_cast<Derived*>(this)->funcImpl();
     }
 protected:
     Base() {}
 };

 class DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA> {
 public:
      DerivedA {}
 protected:
      friend class Base<DerivedA>;
      void funcImpl() {
          // DerivedA special implementation
      }
 }; 

 class DerivedB : public Base<DerivedB> {
 public:
      DerivedB {}
 protected:
      friend class Base<DerivedB>;
      void funcImpl() {
          // DerivedB special implementation
      }
 };
```

This is also well known as the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) -> *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern*.